# Why can't i get simple form theming to work?

Tags: theming, forms

I've got this implementation of hook_theme in a theme :

```
function uncoated_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

  return array(
    'uncoated_user_register_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'element',
    ),
  );

}
```

Furthermore, I've got the following function:

```
function uncoated_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#theme'] = array('uncoated_user_register_form');
}

function theme_uncoated_user_register_form($element) {
  return '<div class="test"></div>";
}
```

However, the function `theme_uncoated_user_register_form` is never invoked. I've also tried to replace `$form['#theme']` with `$form['#theme_wrapper']` to see if I could at least wrap the form in additional markup; but that does not work either.

I can't really see what I'm doing wrong? Drupal seems to be totally ignoring the theme function I'm trying to run the form through.

Comment: Did you cleared the caches after adding the hook and where is your theme function located .module/.inc file?

Comment: I did clear the cache, and the function is located in template.php. In other words, all listed functions reside in the same file...

Comment: put the hook_theme in the  respective module i.e put uncoated_theme function in uncoated module. Then clear the cache and check.

Comment: Is that a copy/paste of your code? If so you have a syntax error in the last functional line (you're opening with a single quote but closing with a double quote). This should give you a white screen/fatal error

Comment: @Clive : thanks, but i added that part "on the run" while writing this question.

Comment: @Mathankumar the uncoated_theme function belongs to the theme itself, and I've put it in the template.php file which belongs to that theme.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the simplest of things...

`$form['#theme']` needs to be a string, not an array, so change

```
$form['#theme'] = array('uncoated_user_register_form');
```

to

```
$form['#theme'] = 'uncoated_user_register_form';
```

Comment: I tried that, however the theme function got invoked in both ways.

Comment: Hmmm, weird, i tried that too...none worked. Does it matter that my theme is a subtheme?

Answer (score -1):

`uncoated_form_user_register_form_alter` -> `hook_form_user_register_form_alter` doesn't seem right. It looks like you're trying to alter the registration form, which is `user_register_form` and not `form_user_register_form`. I'm just guessing but it looks like it should be `uncoated_user_register_form_alter`. So it's not really a case of Drupal ignoring your theming function, you actually wrote a wrong name for the alter function and that never gets called, hence the theme never gets applied. Also specific form alters don't take parameter `$form_id`. If you're having trouble with form id's and naming correct hooks, try using the normal [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) which takes the `$form_id` as the 3rd parameter, and check it against `user_register_form` to apply the theme.

Comment: The hook is `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` so if the module is called "uncoated" then the hook function will definitely be called `uncoated_form_user_register_form_alter()`. That hook does take `$form_id` as a 3rd parameter BTW (it didn't in D6 but does in D7)

Comment: The alter hook is called as it should, but not the theme function itself.

Comment: Ah bummer, I never use hook_form_FORMID_alter :P